# Restrict internet connection

Tags: ipad, internet-connection

Is there any way to restrict internet connection for any applications but currently running (my app)?

May be some configuration profile to make only one application running, or another way?

Comment: Have you got the enterprise developer program?

Comment: Is that can helps? If there only way, then I will have.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is only possible possible with the Enterprise Developer Program. There you can push profiles on the devices. These profiles can contain all kinds of restrictions.

Comment: You mean iPhone Configuration Utility profiles? There is some restrictions, but not enought. Or iDEP has more of them?